# code design // function wrappers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been wondering how to improve this part of code in terms of code
design:

(I'm especially interested in calling the same function with different
default attributes - a lot of code duplication)

```
def follow_pages(number_of_pages = 5, sleep_interval = 5)
  process_pages true, number_of_pages, sleep_interval
end

def unfollow_pages(number_of_pages = 5, sleep_interval = 5)
  process_pages false, number_of_pages, sleep_interval
end

def process_pages(follow = true, number_of_pages = 5, sleep_interval = 5)
  number_of_pages.times do |page|

    sleep rand(sleep_interval)

    if follow
      follow_all_pages
    else
      unfollow_all_pages
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: agreeing with vote down that this is a design question.  I'd like a forum of design discussions, but StackOverflow has a policy against it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do smth like that:

```
def follow_pages(*args)
  process_pages true, *args
end

def unfollow_pages(*args)
  process_pages false, *args
end

def process_pages(follow = true, number_of_pages = 5, sleep_interval = 5)
  ...
end
```

You basically accept any arguments, prepend value for `follow` argument and pass it to the main `proess_page` method. I'm not sure that it makes the code more readable, but it definitely saves you from repeating default values for the arguments.